# Data type is not matching that in table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am doing an add to cart page for my hotel booking system.I have 2 tables,1 reservation which contains numofday and the other table is room containing roomname and roomprice.

For the add to cart, I have to retrieve the value of both table and load it into a gridview, then calculate the price when button book is click (price = numofday*roomprice.I am using session.The difficulty I am facing is that, I it is storing the roomname into the column of roomprice.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
    If Session("sCart") Is Nothing Then
        ds = New DataSet()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("RoomName"))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("RoomPrice", GetType(System.Int32)))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Numofday", GetType(System.Int32)))
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Total", GetType(System.Int32)))
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Session("sCart") = ds
    Else
        ds = DirectCast(Session("sCart"), DataSet)
    End If
    Dim row As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).NewRow()
    row("RoomName") = GridView1.Rows(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Cells(0).Text
    row("RoomPrice") = GridView1.Rows(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Cells(0).Text
    row("Numofday") = GridView1.Rows(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Cells(0).Text.ToString
    row("Total") = CInt(row("Numofday") * row("RoomPrice"))
    ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(row)
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Edit; this error is now occurring:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted your indexes are out on `.Cells(x)`. You're using 0 for each one. These should be changed to represent the correct index. However since I am unsure of your indexes I will use `x`.

I would first change your `RoomPrice` and `Total` types to `Decimal`. `Int32` in the long run may not give you what you are after.

As an example storing 9.99 as an `Int32` will round it to 10. By storing as `Decimal` you will retain 9.99.

Changes these to use `System.Decimal`:

```
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("RoomPrice", GetType(System.Decimal)))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Total", GetType(System.Decimal)))
```

Next I would use [Decimal.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) to set `RoomPrice`:

```
row("RoomPrice") = Decimal.Parse(GridView1.Rows(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Cells(x).Text.ToString())
```

I would also use [Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) to set `Numofday`:

```
row("Numofday") = Int32.Parse(GridView1.Rows(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Cells(x).Text.ToString())
```

If `.Parse` is not giving you what you are after you may want to consider `.TryParse`:

```
Dim s As String = "9.99"
Dim d As Decimal = 0D

If Not Decimal.TryParse(s, d) Then
    'Failed to parse
End If
```

Lastly you will have to change the way you calculate `Total`:

```
row("Total") = CInt(row("Numofday")) * CDec(row("RoomPrice"))
```

As a side note, turn [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement):

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

Edit; OP has updated with a screenshot of an error. The reason for this error is because the column `Total` has not been added. The line for this has been commented out. This has been resolved with the OP through comments.